# OWIN WebApp leads to multiple functions calls

Tags: c#, winforms, owin

I'm afraid this an XY problem but I cannot find a solution by myself.
To narrow down the problem I create a new C# project with an empty form. Here the program.cs code (updated from the original question to have a very minimal example):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private IDisposable webApp;
    const string url = "http://localhost:8080";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Debug.WriteLine("before");
        foo();
        webApp = WebApp.Start<Startup>(url);
        Debug.WriteLine("after");
        foo();
    }

    private void foo()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("foo");
    }
}

class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) { }
}
```

Here the (weird) output:

```
before
foo
after
after
after
foo
foo
foo
```

Removing the `WebApp.Start` call leads to the expected output:

```
before
foo
after
foo
```

Why?

Comment: I am able to reproduce this, though instead of the tripled logs, mine are doubled.  Strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because internally `Debug.Writeline` uses a Trace Listener.  If you inspect the `Trace.Listeners` collection before and after the `WebApp.Start` line, you'll notice that the web app is adding a second trace listener.  So your log messages are getting executed *once*, but are writing to the "log" multiple times, because there are extra listeners.

The application started with a single `DefaultTraceListener`, then the web app starts a `TextWriterTraceListener`.  You can remove the extra listener by adding this to your configuration:

```
Trace.Listeners.Remove("HostingTraceListener");
```

A second option to fix this is to implement your own `ITraceOutputFactory`:

```
public class MyFactory: ITraceOutputFactory
{
    public TextWriter Create(string outFile)
    {
        return TextWriter.Null;
    }
}
```

And register it with your web app:

```
var myFactory = new MyFactory();
var provider = ServicesFactory.Create(fact => fact.AddInstance<ITraceOutputFactory>(myFactory));

WebApp.Start<Startup>(provider, new StartOptions(url)))
```

Comment: This is only related to the `Debug` functions? I discovered that because with the WebApp enabled my class functions and events were actually executed three times.

Comment: This is only related to how `Debug` uses trace listeners.  That *sounds* like a separate issue that needs its own [mcve].  It's worth noting, in this question, your `foo()` method isn't getting called multiple times after you start the web app.  It's getting called once, and logging multiple times.

Comment: @Mark it's entirely possible the two issues are related.  I encourage you to edit your question so it produces the second issue.  At the least, I can look at it and go "nope, different thing".

Comment: @mark if you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting it.  If not, please let me know how it can be improved.  Thanks.

Comment: please let me a bit of time to fully understand what's going on and I will accept it - don't worry.

Comment: @Mark if you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting it. If not, please let me know how it can be improved. Thanks.